# How to pass a pointer to an array from main to a function?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, pass-by-reference, insertion-sort

Basically, I'm trying to set the size of my array according to an input (numArraySize will be asked for from the user). I created an array pointer in main and want to pass this pointer to the functions.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Algorithm for Insertion Sort
int numArraySize; 

void inputNums(int numArray[])
{
    cout << "Enter a bunch of numbers: " ;
    for(int x=0; x<numArraySize; x++)
    {
        cin >> numArray[x];
    }
}
void outputNums(int numArray[])
{
    for(int x=0; x<numArraySize; x++)
    {
        cout << numArray[x];
        if(x != numArraySize-1)
        {
            cout << " - ";
        }
    }
}
void insertionSort(int numArray[])
{
    int num;
    int i;
    for(int j=1; j<numArraySize; j++)
    {
        num = numArray[j];
        i = j-1;
        while(i>=0 && numArray[i] > num)
        {
            numArray[i+1] = numArray[i];
            i--;
        }
        numArray[i+1] = num;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int *numbers = new int[numArraySize];
    int choice;

    cout << "1) Insertion Sort" << endl;
    cout << "Enter your choice: " << endl;

    cin >> choice;              // Input choice for which algorithm to use

    if(choice == 1)
    {
        cout << "Enter size of the array: ";
        cin >> numArraySize;
        inputNums(numbers);         // Insert numbers
        insertionSort(numbers);     // Use algorithm to sort then output
        outputNums(numbers);
    }

    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

Ok i fixed the error. I changed: 
"int numArraySize=1;" 
and the position of
"int *numbers = new int[numArraySize];"

The problem was that i had to initialize the numArraySize anyways. That causes error apparently. And the second problem was i have to input numArraySize before i initialize 
"int *numbers" in the main function.

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    // Algorithm for Insertion Sort
    int numArraySize=1; 

    void inputNums(int numArray[])
    {
        cout << "Enter a bunch of numbers: " ;
        for(int x=0; x<numArraySize; x++)
        {
            cin >> numArray[x];
        }
    }
    void outputNums(int numArray[])
    {
        for(int x=0; x<numArraySize; x++)
        {
            cout << numArray[x];
            if(x != numArraySize-1)
            {
                cout << " - ";
            }
        }
    }
    void insertionSort(int numArray[])
    {
        int num;
        int i;
        for(int j=1; j<numArraySize; j++)
        {
            num = numArray[j];
            i = j-1;
            while(i>=0 && numArray[i] > num)
            {
                numArray[i+1] = numArray[i];
                i--;
            }
            numArray[i+1] = num;
        }
    }

    int main()
    {
        int choice;

        cout << "1) Insertion Sort" << endl;
        cout << "Enter your choice: " << endl;

        cin >> choice;              // Input choice for which algorithm to use

        if(choice == 1)
        {
            cout << "Enter size of the array: ";
            cin >> numArraySize;
            int *numbers = new int[numArraySize];
            inputNums(numbers);         // Insert numbers
            insertionSort(numbers);     // Use algorithm to sort then output
            outputNums(numbers);
        }

    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for your helps :)

Comment: Is this is an academic question or are you working on legacy code? I see no reason why you wouldn't just use a standard container which manages everything for you.

Comment: Just have e.g. `void inputNums(int numArray[])` - no need for the `&`-reference.  Separately, it's generally considered better practice to avoid global variables and pass functions the values they need to operate, as in `void inputNums(int numArray[], int numArraySize)`.  And, you should check that streaming input works - what if the user types 'x' when you're waiting for a number?  Try `if (!(cin >> numArray[x])) { std::cerr << "got a non-numeric input, exiting\n"; exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }`

Comment: What is the problem you are having with this?

Comment: You should post the error or whatever problem you're having.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To pass an array to a function, you can simply use `int *array`:

```
void outputNums(int *numArray)
{
    for(int x=0; x<numArraySize; x++)
    {
        cout << numArray[x];
        if(x != numArraySize-1)
        {
            cout << " - ";
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that it would be better to use a standard container like [a vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: I prefer to use the `[]` syntactic sugar when I want people to know that they should be passing an array.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It doesnt work though. Normally, when i dont make the array a pointer, i get the results perfectly(in this case, the program sorts the entered numbers). But now it just stops working after i enter choice, array size and some numbers.

Comment: @Pycorro You're going to have to explain how it doesn't work, otherwise no one can help further with why.

Comment: @Pycorro I'm glad you find a solution, but you should still consider using standard containers.

Comment: No it didnt work that way. I dont need to have another pointer in functions. A simple array would work just as fine.

Answer (score 0):

When you are allocating the memory for the array in line

```
int *numbers = new int[numArraySize]
```

, you still haven't received the desired size for the array in variable numArraySize.